# Reading data in Spyder with a different encoding

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, spyder

I'm trying to read a .spydata file into Spyder, which was written in a different platform (and probably with a different encoding), but  spyder gives an error : 
    `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`

I tried changing my encoding setting before loading spyder without success. Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you save your data in Python 2 and are trying to load it in Python 3, or vice versa?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Yes, maybe. I received this from another person, and the code was in Python2, so probably its is true.

Comment: Then please try to use Spyder with the same Python version that that file was created with in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the encoding problem with this line on top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/unicode.html

You can change de encoding if you need too. But I don't know if you can include the encoding line on the file you mentioned. Hope It helps.